# Asymptotic lines

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, surfaces

I have a surface $f : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ that is represented by $$f(t, \phi) = (ae^t \cos(\phi),ae^t \sin(\phi), \int_0^t \sqrt{1-a^2 e^{2x}} dx)$$

I also calculated the matrix representation of the Shape operator (or Weingarten map):

$$L(t,\phi):=\left(\begin{matrix} - \frac{ae^{t}}{\sqrt{1-a^2e^{2t}}} & 0 \\ 0  & \sqrt{1-a^2 e^{2t}} e^t a \\ \end{matrix} \right)$$

Now, I want to calculate the asymptotic lines, which are the ones satisfying $II(c'(s),c'(s))=0$.

To do this, I calculated $g_p ( L c'(s),c'(s))=0$ for $c'(s)= (t'(s),\phi'(s))$ and got $-(t'(s))^2+(1-a^2 e^{2t})(\phi'(s))^2=0.$ Thus $t'(s) = \pm |\phi'(s)|\sqrt{1-a^2e^{2t}}.$

Does anybody know how to continue in order to actually get the curves on the surface now?

I mean the problem is that this is an ODE containing two functions, so I think this problem is somehow underdetermined or am I completely wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already realized that the lines of curvature are the $t$- and $\phi$-curves. (This is the case for any surface of revolution.)

For the asymptotic curves, you want to solve the differential equation
$$\frac{d\phi}{dt} = \pm\frac1{\sqrt{1-a^2e^{2t}}}.$$
This comes from your equation relating $v_1$ and $v_2$. (The slope of an asymptotic curve, according to your calculations, is given by the ratio $v_2/v_1$.)

Comment: could you explain a little bit more, why I should do this? I have the impression that you say that I should integrate $v_1 = \pm |v_2| \sqrt{1-a^2e^{2t}}$ for fixed $v_1=1$ in order to get $v_2$, but it would be more natural to me I guess to fix $v_2 = 1$ and go for $v_1$, as this is the same integral then, as we have in the definition of our surface, but I don't really see, why I should do this. I.e. what about the lines of curvature?

Comment: Suppose I tell you that the slope of a curve at the point $(x,y)$ is $f(x,y)$ and ask you to find the curve through a given point $(x_0,y_0)$. Then you integrate $dy/dx = f(x,y)$ with the initial condition $y(x_0)=y_0$. I am suggesting that this is your situation here. ... And I answered your question about lines of curvature in the first sentence. :)

Comment: okay, so I try to repeat this in my words. I have shown that the lines of curvature are $v_{\phi}(t) = (t,\phi)$ and $v_{t}(\phi)=(t,\phi)$, as these curves satisfy that their derivatives are the unit vectors. So the actual curves on the surface are given by $f \circ v_{\phi}$ or $f\circ v_{t}$ respectively. I think I understood this. Now my asymptotic curve in the parameter domain of the surface shall be called $c:I \rightarrow \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $c'(s) = (v_1(s),v_2(s)).$ Now I still don't really see how you got this differential quotient.

Comment: sorry, forgot to ping you.

Comment: I don't understand what you aren't getting here. I already explained that the differential equation comes from saying that the slope of $c$ at $c(s)$ is $v_2(s)/v_1(s)$. Since $c(s)=(t(s),\phi(s))$, that slope will be $d\phi/dt$.

Comment: well, I mean I don't see why we want to look at this. We want to determine $\phi(s)$ and $t(s)$, cause then our asymptotic curves on the surface are given by $(f \circ c)(s)$. Now even if I integrate our ODE, all I get is $\phi(t(s))$, which looks like some kind of reparametrization, but what I don't see is, why I know that I can write $\phi$ in terms of $t$, cause $t(s)$ could be zero and $\phi(s)$ some linearly increasing function or is this impossible? So I am sorry, but your ODE came very unexpected to me.

Comment: Most cases this differential equation will give you only an implicit answer. Sometimes you can do better.

Comment: well, in this case: the antiderivative is easily found by using wolframalpha http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2Fsqrt%281-a^2*e^%282*t%29%29+dt but is there any way to proceed from this position?

Comment: somehow I think, I am either not seeing the final answer ( which is finding the representation of the curve)

Comment: I get something like $\tanh(\phi-c) = \pm\sqrt{1-a^2e^{2t}}$. As I said, you expect to get some sort of an implicit relation. I suppose you could write $\phi = c\pm\operatorname{arctanh}\left(\sqrt{1-a^2e^{2t}}\right)$, if you prefer.